# Create new dialog on clicking push button

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am creating an application which initially show login and signup buttons.
On click of login i want to show another screen(or dialog) which will allow user to enter username and password.

And i want to hide first dialog when second dialog has showed up but was not able to do that.(Just like we have in facebook messenger)

Can we open a new dialog by connecting to clicked signal of login pushbutton in Qt dsigner itself ?

I have designed first screen in Qt designer, converted that .ui file to .py and then imported it in main.py

*main.py*

```
import sys
from Pyside.QtGui import *
from Pyside.QtCore import *
from firstscreen import Ui_Dialog


class MainDialog(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Login.clicked.connect(self.showsecondscreen)

    def showsecondscreen(self):
        newScreen = QDialog(self)
        newScreen.show(self)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainDialog()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

*firstscreen.ui*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui version="4.0">
     <class>Dialog</class>
     <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>322</width>
        <height>300</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="windowTitle">
       <string>My App</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="Login">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>110</x>
         <y>110</y>
         <width>98</width>
         <height>27</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Login</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="Signup">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>110</x>
         <y>150</y>
         <width>98</width>
         <height>27</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Signup</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
     <resources/>
     <connections/>
    </ui>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
def showsecondscreen(self):
    self.hide(self)
    newScreen = QDialog(self)
    newScreen.show(self)
```

?

Anyhow, the design is not very good, as you try to use the Qt-Application-init-pattern with dialogs.  This will make the class MainDialog run within the master event loop - so after it gets closed, your application is closed.  So only hide works.

Normally you'd execute a QDialog with exec() and use the returned result for further processing.

If you plan to show a Mainwindow after logging in, it might be better to rename your "MainDialog" class to "LoginDialog", then create the real application's Main Window (might as well call that class "MainWindow").  Then change the startup like this:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
login = LoginDialog()
if(login.exec() == LOGGED_IN_SUCCESSFULLY_RETURN_VALUE)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Update: if this shall become a sequence of dialogs, like a Wizard (or "assistant" as called on MacOSX), then maybe you'd want to derive from `QWizard`.